# How to restore a mongodb backup on a replicaSet?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I made a local backup of my mongodb (version 4) by doing

```
mongodump -u adminUser --authenticationDatabase admin --gzip --archive=/tmp/file.gz --db <dbname>
```

Now I would like to restore this data to my remote mongodb, which is a replicaset with two replicas running on a kubernetes cluster.

Normaly I would use

```
mongorestore -u adminUser --authenticationDatabase admin --gzip --archive=/tmp/file.gz
```

But how do I do this restore on a replicaset architecture?

Do I have to run a shell on any pod instance?

```
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -n mongodb -- bash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect to a replica set. It needs to be set in connection string uri:

```
mongorestore --uri="mongodb://adminUser:password@hostname1,hostname2,hostname3/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=<replSetName>"
```

according documentation you can specify the replica set also with `--host` parameter

```
mongorestore -u adminUser --authenticationDatabase admin --host=<replSetName>/hostname1,hostname2,hostname3
```

`mongorestore` will connect to the PRIMARY member, data is restored into there and then replicated to SECONDARY members.

If you have to restore a lot of data, then consider [Sync by Copying Data Files from Another Member](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/rapid/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/#sync-by-copying-data-files-from-another-member)